# Vagrant php5-mysql not working

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I'm running a Virtualbox Environment (laravel project) that I haven't touched in a while.

When I SSH into vagrant and try running the 'php' command, I get the following error:

```
vagrant@sched:/etc/php5/mods-available$ php
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: pdo_parse_params in Unknown on line 0
^C
vagrant@sched:/etc/php5/mods-available$ php
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: pdo_parse_params in Unknown on line 0
```

Any ideas where to proceed from here? I tried to purge my php5 and php5-mysql installations and re-installing, but it seems that didn't do anything.

Comment: Check [vagrant issue 112](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV/issues/112). For a user `vagrant destroy && vagrant up` helped